# Silverlight control inside browser issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, silverlight

i made control to access my scanner and make scan and it worked fine on development and localhost but when access through intranet it made error while trying to createobject and same issue when using getobject instead
the error is system.notsupportedexception[comAutomation_featureBlocked]

```
             using (dynamic CommonDialog = AutomationFactory.CreateObject("WIA.CommonDialog"))
        {
            dynamic imageFile = CommonDialog.ShowAcquireImage(
                          (int)WiaDeviceType.ScannerDeviceType,
                          (int)WiaImageIntent.ColorIntent,
                          (int)WiaImageBias.MaximizeQuality,
                          FormatID.wiaFormatJPEG, false, true, false);
            if (imageFile != null)
            {

                string filePath = string.Format(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.InternetCache)+"{0}.jpg", Guid.NewGuid());

               // string filePath = string.Format("C:\\tempScan\\{0}.jpg", Guid.NewGuid());
                imageFile.SaveFile(filePath);
                FileInfo info = new FileInfo(filePath);
                UploadFile(filePath, info.OpenRead());
               // MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Saved {0}", filePath));

            }


        }
```

Comment: For this you have to make Elevated Permissions (especially in browser). https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg192793(v=vs.95).aspx

Comment: I made this procedures before and the problem still exists the iis server is windows server 2012 and the client is IE11